# Django QuerySet/Manager filter employees by age from birthday

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am a beginner. I would like to get list employees have age > 25 and calculate the average age of employees. Currently, we need to get age from birthday (I have no idea about it ^^)
. Please help me create sample QuerySet/Manager about it.

Thanks all :))

My model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
""""Employee model"""

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.DateField(max_length=8)
```

Note: Not get all employees and filter from the results. (`results = Employee.objects.all()`) and not use Raw SQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for custom managers here is one suggetion.

```
import datetime
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EmployeeManager, self).get_queryset()

    def get_queryset_age_greater_25(self):
        # The `iterator()` method ensures only a few rows are fetched from the database at a time, saving memory.
        ids = [obj.id for obj in self.get_queryset().iterator() if obj.find_age() > 25]
        return self.get_queryset().filter(id__in=ids)

    def get_avg(self):
        sum_, count = sum(
            map(lambda obj: obj.find_age(), self.get_queryset_age_greater_25().iterator())), self.get_queryset_age_greater_25().count()
        return sum_/count


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    objects = EmployeeManager()

    def find_age(self):
        return datetime.date.today().year - self.birthday.year
```

Then use

```
Employee.objects.get_queryset_age_greater_25() # to get employee objects having age greater than 25)
Employee.objects.get_avg() # to get avg age of employees having age greater than 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

qs = Employee.objects.filter(birthdate__gt=date.today() - relativedelta(years=+25))
```

Expected that 25 years + 1 day is enough. The function `relativedelta` is used due to leap-year, to not raise ValueError exception on 02/29/2020.

Comment: Thanks, I have applied it to get list employee have age > 25, how about *calculate the average age of employees*?

Comment: I don't remember a modern exact solution by [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/), but I'm sure that it exists. A classic solution is something to combine Django with Python evaluation finally. Maybe `Avg('birthdate')` if possible or to calculate the average to the January 1st without age fractions (`Avg('birthdate__year')` or average Julian date etc.

Comment: `Avg('birthdate__year')` not right in some case, we should know exact age to use Avg. Thanks for your support, I will research more.

Comment: You can publish your answer here because the best one obsoleted on SO is by [`extra avg(UNIX_TIMESTAMP...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2365044/448474).